# iPhone: What is MPMusicPlaybackStateInterrupted? And what is difference between it and MPMusicPlaybackStatePaused

Tags: iphone, ios, mpmusicplayercontroller

I have some questions about `MPMusicPlayerController`'s `playbackState` properties.

In the document, `MPMusicPlaybackStateInterrupted` and `MPMusicPlaybackStatePaused` are defined as follows:

**MPMusicPlaybackStateInterrupted**
The music player has been interrupted, such as by an incoming phone call.

**MPMusicPlaybackStatePaused**
The music player is paused.

I can't check incoming phone call because I don't have iPhone now.
But only a few times I got `MPMusicPlaybackStateInterrupted` state while just playing music with iPod touch.

(I don't know why the interrupted state happened. There was no incoming phone call and no other operations except for just playing music).

And at those times, `MPMusicPlayerController` just paused playing music.

**Question1**
What is the difference between `MPMusicPlaybackStateInterrupted` and `MPMusicPlaybackStatePaused`?

**Question2**
When does `MPMusicPlaybackStateInterrupted` happen except for incoming phone call?

**Question3**
What should I do when I get `MPMusicPlaybackStateInterrupted`?
For example, when I get `MPMusicPlaybackStatePaused` or `MPMusicPlaybackStateStopped`, I should change play/pause button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I confirmed the following information with iOS 5.1.1.

**Question1**
What is the difference between `MPMusicPlaybackStateInterrupted` and `MPMusicPlaybackStatePaused`?

`MPMusicPlaybackStatePaused` happens when the player paused.
`MPMusicPlaybackStateInterrupted` happens when the player is interrupted by other audio output such as incoming phone call or timer of Apple's Clock app.

**Question2**
When does `MPMusicPlaybackStateInterrupted` happen except for incoming phone call?

`MPMusicPlaybackStateInterrupted` happens when timer of Clock app rings.
`-applicationWillResignActive:` also is called when the timer rings.
But `MPMusicPlaybackStatePaused` doesn't happen and playing music is automatically resumed after interruption (the alarm of the timer) finished.

Other examples of interruption are Siri/Voice Control(hold down home button), remote control of earphone(if you use applicationMusicPlayer), incoming phone call.
Pushing play button of remote control of earphone doesn't make the app resign active. And the interruption never finish.

`MPMusicPlaybackStateInterrupted` doesn't happen and playback state doesn't change when notification banner appears on top of the screen.
VoiceOver also doesn't generate interruption.

**Question3**
What should I do when I get `MPMusicPlaybackStateInterrupted`?
For example, when I get `MPMusicPlaybackStatePaused` or `MPMusicPlaybackStateStopped`, I should change play/pause button.

You don't have to do anything in callback of `MPMusicPlayerControllerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification` when `MPMusicPlaybackStateInterrupted` happens.
Because playing music is automatically resumed after interruption.

**EDIT**
I found that infrequently playing music is not resumed automatically.(That means you can't rely on automatic resume.)

And in the following cases playing music is not resumed automatically.

- When remote control button of earphone was pushed. (if you use applicationMusicPlayer)
- When timer rang, you double-tap home button, switch application, stop timer, and switch back to the application.
- When you switched back to the app while you are calling after you accepted incoming call.